# Android Kotlin - How do I assign a name function in main activity class to setOnClickListener in another class?

Tags: android, events, kotlin

Please check the sample code and comments below,

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MyListener {
  fun OnViewItemClicked(){
    // do something
  }
}

class AnotherClass() : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    // how do i set this to OnViewItemClicked declared in class MainActivity?
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(OnViewItemClicked);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the `Listener instance` to the adapter:- like :-

```
val adapter = AnotherClass(this@MainActivity)
```

Then in adapter

```
class AnotherClass(private val listener: MainActivity): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
     ....
     ....
     holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
         listener.OnViewItemClicked()
     }
     ....
 }
```

**Explanation** - 
This is done with the help of `kotlin lambda` , i.e, equivalent to :-

```
val clickLambda: (View) -> Unit = {
    listener.OnViewItemClicked()
}
```

**Edit** :- Instead of doing this you can directly pass in a lambda of type `(View) -> Unit` from the activity !

Comment: That should be `val listener: MyListener` not `MainActivity`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler anything is fine , both of them should work. Anyway, the `questioner` dint `override` `OnViewItemClicked` in the activity. `OnViewItemClicked` is a simple method not an overidden one. So i would stick to my answer ! :p

Comment: @SantanuSur `OnViewItemClicked` does not override anything - even if the method resolves, it does not call the implementation of an `interface`. If this is wrong in Java, this is wrong in Kotlin, too.

Comment: @MartinZeitler The interface `MyListener` **does not** have any method as per the question (if at all its an interface )! So it would be useless if we seek for `MyListener` in the adapter. Again we need to cast it to `MainActivity`. Am i getting anything wrong ?

Comment: @SantanuSur The problem with the question is, that `MainActivity implements MyListener` but does not `override` that `interface`. Passing `MyListener` implementation as `listener` would rather be syntactically correct - instead of passing `MainActivity` and calling it `listener`.